# Android sliding items horizontal like in Duolingo App

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, sliding, horizontallist

I was playing around try to implement sliding functionality like in Duolingo Activity with horizontal lessons list. The link to screen capture of this functionality [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAq2-Uexv7A).
[image: Screenshot]

With horizontal slider the sliding has no such effects. What will be the proper way to implement such UX sliding widget?

Could I costumize the default ListView with adding the transition effect?
Or could be it possible to do it with CardView?
Do some external lib offer this like [twoway-view](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use classic ViewPager to show content and then apply to pager this PageTransformer:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            mPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
                @Override
                public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
                    final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
                    page.setScaleX(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.5f);
                    page.setScaleY(normalizedposition / 2 + 0.5f);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I was gonna answer the same. That's certainly a ViewPager with custom `PageTransformer`.  Also don't forget to override `getPageWidth` on your Pager adapter and return something like `0.8f`

Comment: MiroM That is very close to that I am looking for. And Budius scaling with overriding getPageWidth is also ok, but my fragments now arent centered. Every time I slide the ViewPager the fragments get stick to the left margin of display. And The last fragment stays scaled.

Comment: Ok, so I used custom `PageTransformer`, but without Overriding `getPageWidth`. I had problems with centering and last fragment was not responding correct. Instead I added the paddings on the ViewPager in layout file and the used `android:clipToPadding`. Got the other part of the solution from [link](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact requirement for your postings. Kindly go through this URL https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow. Download the zip and run the sample. Enjoy!! Its easy to customize too...