# How to animate UICollectionViewCell Size

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to animate collectionView Cell like here:

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/147165/screenshots/2232500/duolingo3.gif

I think they used here CollectionView.

```
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.width - 300)/2, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width - 440)/2);

    UIView.transitionWithView(collectionView, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

        cell.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - 200
    cell.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 100
    }, completion: nil)
```

I have size transition but look different. I try to make this animation in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: I'm sure that they implemented a custom transition. You can read about it here: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/

Comment: If its true... I have another problem. How to add few boxes like in this animation.

Comment: I found similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025433/android-sliding-items-horizontal-like-in-duolingo-app

Can someone translate it to objc or swift?

Comment: Why don't you try to translate it yourself, and then let us know if you have any difficulties?

Comment: I'm trying but its hard to understand.

Comment: link is broken.